# Show that for all $f\in\mathcal{M}(X,\tau,\hat{\mathbb{R}})$ exist a sequence that converges pointwise to $f$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau)$ a measure space ($X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). I prove that, for all $f\in\mathcal{M}(X,\tau,\hat{\mathbb{R}})$ exist a sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\xi(X,\tau,\mathbb{R})$ that converges pointwise to $f$, but I cannot finish the following problem

Where $\xi(X,\tau,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of simples function to real values.

> Now, Let $\mu$ a measure $\sigma$-finite defined on $\tau$. Show that that sequences of functions (of that I mentioned) is choose of way that, each $f_{n}$ is in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(X,\tau,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function#Relation_to_Lebesgue_integration

Comment: Hint: Take your original $(f_n)$ and then use $\sigma$-finiteness to chop the $f_n$ sequence into functions with support of finite measure.